# Bootstrap Validator for select fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqbootstrapvalidation

Trying to require that both drop down selection boxes have a chosen option before submit is enabled to be clicked. What is missing that is not allowing the plugin to check for validation?

**FORM:**

```
<form role="form" id="bootstrapSelectForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <br>
      <h5>Region</h5>
        <select class="form-control" name="region" id="region" >
                   <option value="">Select a Region</option>
                   <option value="US">US</option>
                   <option value="UK">UK</option>
                   <option value="Sales Team">XS (Sales Team)</option>
                   <option value="Editorial Test">XT (Editorial Test)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <br>
      <h5>Duration</h5>
        <select class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" >
                   <option value="">Select a Duration</option>
                   <option value="5">5 Minutes</option>
                   <option value="10">10 Minutes</option>
                   <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
                   <option value="20">20 Minutes</option>
                   <option value="25">25 Minutes</option>
                   <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Bootstrap Validator:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#bootstrapSelectForm')
    .find('[name="region"]')
        .selectpicker()
        .submit(function(e) {
            $('#bootstrapSelectForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'region');
        })
        .end()
    .find('[name="duration"]')
        .selectpicker()
        .submit(function(e) {
            $('#bootstrapSelectForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'duration');
        })
        .end()
    .bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            region: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Please select region',

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            duration: {
                validators: {
                        message: 'Please select region.'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to make **BootstrapValidator** work together with other plugin, you should follow two rules below:

1. Don't exclude the field if the plugin changes the field visibility

Some plugins hide your field and create new elements to change how the field looks like. By default, the hidden, invisible fields will not be validated. Therefore, you need to set

```
 excluded: ':disabled'
```

See the [excluded](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#form-excluded) option for more information.

2. Revalidate the field if the plugin changes its value dynamically:

Most plugins trigger an event after changing the field value. By using this kind of event handler, you need to ask BootstrapValidator to revalidate the field.

In your case, you have just to do the following:

- Add the `excluded` option.
- Use `notEmpty` validator instead of the `Callback` validator.
- Instead of using `.submit` use `.change` in order to revalidate the field when it's changed.

See code bellow:

```
$('#bootstrapSelectForm')
   .find('[name="region"]')
     .selectpicker()
       .change(function(e) {
         $('#bootstrapSelectForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'region');
       })
       .end()
   .find('[name="duration"]')
     .selectpicker()
      .change(function(e) {
        $('#bootstrapSelectForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'duration');
      })
      .end()
   .bootstrapValidator({
      feedbackIcons: {
         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      excluded: ':disabled', // <=== Add the excluded option
      fields: {
         region: {
            validators: {
               notEmpty: { // <=== Use notEmpty instead of Callback validator
                  message: 'Please select region'
               }
            }
         }
         duration: {
             validators: {
                notEmpty: { // <=== Use notEmpty instead of Callback validator
                   message: 'Please select region.'
                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
 });
```

See [Bootstrap Select](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/bootstrap-select/) example for more information.